# How to create a crosstab with concatenation on pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe **log**

```
  order  row   column     
  1      3     B   
  2      6     U        
  3      3     U       
  4      7     C
  5      6     B
```

I want to create a dataframe where each row corresponds to a number from **row**, and the **sequence value** is created by concatenating the values from **column** in the order from **order**:

```
        sequence
  3     BU
  6     UB
  7     C
```

Is there a (fast) way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `sort_values` by order, then `groupby` on `row` and make sure you use `sort=False`. Then finally we use `GroupBy.agg` and `join` the strings:

```
dfg = (
    df.sort_values("order")
    .groupby("row", sort=False)["column"].agg("".join)
    .reset_index(name="sequence")
)
```

```
   row sequence
0    3       BU
1    6       UB
2    7        C
```

Answer (score 2):

This does the job

```
df.groupby('row')['column'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(list(x)))
```

Output

```
3    BU
6    UB
7     C
```